# Probability of reaching node $A$ from node $B$ in exactly $X$ steps (Graph Theory)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a three-node matrix with two edges ($A$-$B$ and $A$-$C$). I would like to determine what the probability is starting from $B$ and ending at $C$ in exactly $100$ steps.

I have only written out probabilities:
\begin{align*}
    P(A|B) &= 1   \\
    P(B|A) &= 0.5 \\
    P(A|C) &= 1   \\
    P(C|A) &= 0.5
\end{align*}

But there are so many combinations of ways to get from $B$ to $C$ in exactly $100$ steps using these probabilities. Any suggestions on how to continue this problem?

Comment: What is the 100th power of your adjacency matrix?

Comment: Thank  you. I did this, and then multiplied that by the transition matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an odd number of steps, you will always be at $A$.  After an even number of steps, you are equally likely to be at $B$ and at $C$.  Hence the desired answer is $1/2$.